# find a number of tags in html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find

```
var findnumberoftags = "<p>hihih</p><h2></h2><li>one</li><li>two</li><p>iam the best</p><h1>yes</h1><h2></h2>"
```

I want to find the numbers of `<h2>` tags in my string? How can i do that?

```
OUTPUT: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the string as a jquery object, then you can use jquery methods to count the tags.

```
var findnumberoftags ="<p>hihih</p><h2></h2><li>one</li><li>two</li><p>iam the best</p><h1>yes</h1><h2></h2>";
alert($(findnumberoftags ).filter("h2").length)
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/37pAZ/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Using RegEx for example:

```
console.log( findnumberoftags.match( /<h2>/g ).length );
```